# A weird float thing with Javascript

Tags: javascript, google-maps

I am trying to implement google maps into my application, the weird thing happens as my app calls,

```
new google.maps.LatLng(39.776637,30.520544‎);
```

The code returns "Unexpected token ILLEGAL"

but if i delete the last 4 and rewrite it manually from my keyboard,

```
new google.maps.LatLng(39.776637,30.520544);
```

the code works without any problems.

Comment: You're picking up a weird character when you're cutting/pasting. Do whatever you're doing to copy the string from wherever you're copying it, and then go here: http://gutfullofbeer.net/escape.html . Paste into the big textarea and then click the "URL Encode" button. If you see something funny, then that's your problem.

Comment: %u200 there is this little guy. Thank you